# Sagemath :Replace an expression in a formula by a function define previously

Tags: sagemath

I have defined a function F by $F(x)=(f(x)+h)/g(x)$ where $f, g$ are functions and $h$ a variable.

Suppose that I write $f(x)+h$, how can i ask to sagemath to use F in the result: $F(x)*g(x)$

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think it's better now

Comment: I think this is a LOT harder than asking Sage to replace `F(x)` by your formula.  Because in principle, `f(x)+h` really isn't the same - `g(x)=0` would cause `F*g` to not be in its domain.  But of course because it's hard to find things that are missing anyway.

Comment: This is a programming question, not a math question, and should be migrated or closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This challenge resists a bit and requires perseverance.

Setting: three functions, one variable, one relation.

```
sage: f = function('f')
sage: g = function('g')
sage: F = function('F')
sage: h = SR.var('h')
sage: relation = F(x) == (f(x) + h)*g(x)
```

Warm-up: substituting a subexpression by a chosen
replacement in an expression works:

```
sage: a = (f(x) + h)*g(x)
sage: a
(h + f(x))*g(x)
sage: a.subs({f(x) + h: F(x)})
F(x)*g(x)
```

Sage will however not go out of its lengths and rearrange things to
force a substitution we have in mind but don't describe precisely:

```
sage: b = f(x) + h
sage: b
h + f(x)
sage: b.subs({(f(x) + h)/g(x): F(x)})
h + f(x)
```

There just was no actual occurrence of the given subexpression
to substitute, so nothing happened.

If we tell it exactly what to substitute, it will:

```
sage: b.subs({f(x) + h: F(x)*g(x)})
F(x)*g(x)
```

If we are willing to prepare the ground "by hand", we can divide
by g(x) to make the desired subexpression appear, remultiply
immediately to cancel out the division, but hold the multiplication
so the cancellation does not actually get simplified, and then
substitute:

```
sage: bb = (b / g(x)).mul(g(x), hold=True)
sage: bb
((h + f(x))/g(x))*g(x)
sage: bb.subs({(f(x) + h)/g(x): F(x)})
F(x)*g(x)
```

Now that we are warmed up, let us restate our goal: get rid of
any occurrence of `f(x)` in an expression, applying appropriate
substitutions, derived from the relation in the question.

Recall the relation that we want to use for replacements.

```
sage: relation = F(x) == (f(x) + h)*g(x)
```

Introduce an auxiliary variable, say `z`, and substitute it
for the expression to remove in the relation, and solve
to get our replacement dictionary:

```
sage: z = SR.var('z')
sage: fz = {f(x): z}
sage: rep = solve(relation.subs(fz), z, solution_dict=True)
sage: rep
[{z: -(h*g(x) - F(x))/g(x)}]
```

The dictionary came in a list, let's unwrap it out of that list.

```
sage: rep = rep[0]
sage: rep
{z: -(h*g(x) - F(x))/g(x)}
```

Now we can use that to substitute, first replacing `f(x)` by `z`,
then `z` by the result of solving for `z` in the modified relation:

```
sage: b
h + f(x)
sage: b.subs(fz).subs(rep)
h - (h*g(x) - F(x))/g(x)
```

Almost there... try simplifying...

```
sage: b.subs(fz).subs(rep).simplify()
h - (h*g(x) - F(x))/g(x)
```

Didn't work... try harder...

```
sage: b.subs(fz).subs(rep).simplify_full()
F(x)/g(x)
```

We did it!

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: math stack exchange is a lot better than ask.sagemath. I don't know why they choose to maintain that garbage. No moderators, no clear answers (compared to math stack exchange). They could have just let the answers be on stack exchange instead of splitting it :(