# Substitute variables in an expression in Sagemath

Tags: sagemath

Somewhat similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383818/sagemath-replace-an-expression-in-a-formula-by-a-function-define-previously), I was trying to evaluate a Boolean expression given the right hand side variables in [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/). For simplicity, say, my Boolean expression is, $y=x_0+x_1$. For each of $(x_0,x_1) \in \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$, I want to evaluate $y$.

This is the basic code block to get started. Note that, when I tried separate substitution, it works. But it does not work when I tried to automatically substitute variables.

```
B = BooleanPolynomialRing(3, ['x0', 'x1', 'y'])
B.inject_variables()

y = x0 + x1

# This is what I want to evaluate (working fine, but cannot automate, see below)
print (eval('y').subs(x0=0, x1=0))
print (eval('y').subs(x0=0, x1=1))
print (eval('y').subs(x0=1, x1=0))
print (eval('y').subs(x0=1, x1=1))

# This is the part where I tried to automate
from itertools import product
for x in product([0, 1], repeat=2):
    print (y) #### How to automatically substitute variables?
```

I tried multiple ways including various substitution, `eval`, `sage_eval` and `exec`. Got various errors including

- `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`
- `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
- `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'items'`
- `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
- `KeyError: 'x'`
- `AttributeError: 'sage.rings.polynomial.pbori.pbori.BooleanMonomial' object has no attribute 'items'`
- `TypeError: subs() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)`

Therefore, my query is how can I automatically substitute `x`-variables to evaluate `y`?

Comment: This is a programming question, not a math question, and should be closed or migrated.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I agree/understand, but as you can see from the linked question this type of question has been asked/answered before.

Comment: Alas, that old linked question somehow slipped by the community.  It should have also been closed or migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
z = x0 + x1 # didn't want to redefine y
for x in product([0, 1], repeat=2):
    print(z.subs({x0:x[0], x1:x[1]}))
```

First, no need for `eval('z')`: just `z` works fine. Second, pass a dictionary to `subs`, keys are the "variables" like `x0`, values are what you want to substitute for them.

This is a little more "automatic":

```
for x in product([0, 1], repeat=2):
    d = dict(zip((x0, x1), x))
    print(z.subs(d))
```

and even more:

```
for x in product([0, 1], repeat=2):
    d = dict(zip(B.gens()[:-1], x))
    print(z.subs(d))
```

This assumes that the generators for `B` look like `(x0, x1, ..., xn, y)` and you are going to substitute the entries of `x` for all but the last of them: `B.gens()` gives the generators, and `B.gens()[:-1]` gives all but the last generator.

Comment: Can we use `z.variables()` somehow to automatically get the variables? I did not want to explicitly pass the variables.

Comment: Sure, try `z.variables()` instead of `B.gens()[:-1]` in the last example.